# using another class in webpy

Tags: python, web.py

I have to import another class in webpy
Web.py

```
urls = (
    '/', "Home"
)
class Web:

    def __init__(self):
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()
```

home.py

```
class Home:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"
```

can any one tell me why this is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both files are in the same folder then you may try this:

```
urls = (
    '/', "home.Home"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
import web
from home import Home
```

to your main module should do the trick for the import.

Then, your web app is not started until you instantiate your `Web` class. Why don't you just follow the tutorial code and say

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

instead?

Comment: Because the main method is in another class so i thought of starting it in constructor.

Comment: Ok. But `run` may be blocking. Then you cannot do anything after the `run` call unless it happens in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

To import from other paths just add at start of entrypoint:

```
sys.path.insert(0, './$srcdir')
```

And select class from module:

```
...
routes = ('/', 'controllers.IndexController')
....
```